# Filtering by multiple columns with specific string then mutate in one column in R

Tags: r

```r
data <- data.frame(
  "grammer" = c("Python","C","Java","GO",NA,"SQL"),
  "score" = c(1,2,NA,4,7,10),
  "file" = c("GHG.txt", "GXG.ect", NA , "VAC.ect", "GBA.ect", "GHG.txt"),
  "file2" = c("GHG.txt", "GXG.dat", "AGG.ect", "VAC.txt", "GBA.dat", "GHG.dat"),
  "file3" = c("GHG.dat", "GXG.txt", "AGG.dat", "VAC.dat", "GBA.txt", NA )
)
```

I want to get suffix `.ect` from columns (file, file2, file3) and mutate in new column.

Following is my code. I want change to filter simultaneously.

```r
d1 <- data %>% 
  filter(str_detect(file, ".ect")) %>%
  mutate(sub("\\..*", "", file))

d2 <- data %>% 
  filter(str_detect(file2, ".ect")) %>%
  mutate(sub("\\..*", "", file2))

d3 <- data %>% 
  filter(str_detect(file3, ".ect")) %>%
  mutate(sub("\\..*", "", file3))
```

Here is my expected outcome :

[image]

Comment: Please share how exactly your expected outcome should look like.

Comment: @ deschen , corrected outcome pic here , thank you!

Comment: Your example in the code doesn't match your screenshot, e.g. in row 1 there is no "GHG.ect" in either of the files in your data.

Comment: Apart from that, see my updated solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `across`:

```
library(tidyverse)
data |> 
  mutate(new = apply(across(c(file, file2, file3)), 1, function(x) str_remove(str_subset(c(x), ".ect"), ".ect$")))
```

which gives:

```
  grammer score    file   file2   file3 new
1  Python     1 GHG.txt GHG.txt GHG.dat    
2       C     2 GXG.ect GXG.dat GXG.txt GXG
3    Java    NA    <NA> AGG.ect AGG.dat AGG
4      GO     4 VAC.ect VAC.txt VAC.dat VAC
5    <NA>     7 GBA.ect GBA.dat GBA.txt GBA
6     SQL    10 GHG.txt GHG.dat    <NA>
```

Note, if there is no match, this solution just returns an empty character value, i.e. `""`, whereas the screenshot from TO wants a missing value `NA`. This can be achieved by a simple ifelse recode, so not adding it to the code here.

Comment: @FenNei if it solves your problem, please consider flagging this as your accepted answer.

Comment: @  deschen ! OK!!!